# phone disconnects from PC after while

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, miui, xiaomi

my phone disconnects from usb after a while but keeps charging. When plugged to wall charger it does charge, but there is no notification and it even says "connect to charger" when battery is low. I thought it's just the usb port, but it DOES connect and only disconnect after a while and I do not move the cable/phone so I think the problem is with the software. I've tried using different cable. Additionally the phone restarts sometimes, but only if the screen was locked. I've set sleep to "never" and it does not restart.

- phone: Xiaomi Redmi 3 Pro
- android version: 5.1.1 LMY47V
- MIUI version: MIUI 7.5 | Stable 7.5.2.0(LAICNDE)

Thanks for advise.

EDIT: After factory reset the phone doesn't restart anymore, but USB still ain't working

Comment: we have the same problem with the 7A (I usually need to put it on "ultra battery" saver to bypass this bug)